# Run Visual Studio debug session with credentials

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, credentials, integrated-security

Currently I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC 2 website. Company policy says that as many of the connections to backend systems should be done with integrated security.

So finally when the website is hosted in IIS, the credentials of the AppPool are being used to connect to databases, Active Directory and so on. But for now, I'm not hosting in IIS yet. Which brings me to my question:

Is it possible to run the Visual Studio debugging sessions under specific credentials to be able to test the integrated security sessions better?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of running your website under the VS development server, you can debug the website by using IIS on your local machine. In this way you can still debug, but having the added ability to modify the AppPool credentials.

Comment: I understand that's a possibility, but I really like to stay in Visual Studio for debugging.

Comment: You will - the debugger will automatically attached to the IIS process and provide you the same debugging functionality - no need to go out of VS. `F5` will work as normal.

Comment: Yeah allright, I see now. Another suggestion I got: just start Visual Studio with the credentials it should be used with integrated security. That way even all database wizards/dialogs are the way you'd expect.

Comment: @monty - care to further explain - ahh i see, on win7 shift+right click on VS shortcut. Select run as Different user...interesting.